# How to set focus on a control within a custom control?

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2012, objectlistview

I have a custom control containing a textbox and a button. I use the custom control as an editing control for a specific column in an ObjectListView.

On CellEditStarting event I do:

```
private void datalistViewProducts_CellEditStarting(object sender, CellEditEventArgs e)
{
    var ctl = (MyCustomControl)e.Control;
    e.Control = ctl;
}
```

The ObjectListView's `ConfigureControl` method already calls the control's `Select` method. It works fine if I have a usercontrol inheriting directly from a standard TextBox.

So I added the following code to my usercontrol:

```
public new void Select()
{
    textBox.Select();
}
```

However, having a usercontrol as described above, the `Select` method does not move the focus to the textbox.

What am I missing here?

Comment: Thanks, Brother! ('Me Too', just because I often see those together, however have now idea what it means)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way that made it finally work was to add the following code in the usercontrol:

```
protected override void OnEnter(EventArgs e)
{
    base.OnEnter(e);
    textBox.Select();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can create a method in CustomUserControl, say `FocusControl(string controlName)`
and then call this method to focus the control in Custom Control.

> Create the method in your custom User Control-

```
public void FocusControl(string controlName)
    {
        var controls = this.Controls.Find(controlName, true);
        if (controls != null && controls.Count() == 1)
        {
            controls.First().Focus();
        }
    }
```

> Call this method-

```
//textBox1 is the name of your focussing control in Custom User Control
userControl11.FocusControl("textBox1");
```

Comment: @Ivan-MarkDebono, What kind of control you are trying to focus ? and from which control ?

Comment: A simple textbox within a custom control. The custom control is used as an editing control for an ObjectListView.

Comment: also, is your custom user control being focused ? you can check this with Focused Property.- **userControl11.Focused**

Comment: No. It returns false.

Comment: that is the reason for it to be not happening. This happens because your customusercontrol is a repository editor for a  ObjectListBox.